# I Got A Problam In Whatsapp Sharing Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i have a button when i click on this button then whatsapp opens and when i click in a chat and want to send massege then all things come properly but full url not come because **&** included in my url.

My Url is like this

```
www.yoururl.com?1st=1&2nd=2&3rd=2&4th=1&5th=2&6th=2&7th=2&8th=2&9th=2&10th=2&share=share&name=s
```

But sharing in whatsapp then comes only

```
www.yoururl.com?1st=1
```

when i remove first **&** Then url is comes

```
www.yoururl.com?1st=12nd=2
```

so i want to share full url with **&**

Here Is javascript code Code

```
  var url1 = "?1st=" + encodeURIComponent(selectedOption1) + "&2nd=" + encodeURIComponent(selectedOption2) + "&3rd=" + encodeURIComponent(selectedOption3) + "&4th=" + encodeURIComponent(selectedOption4) + "&5th=" + encodeURIComponent(selectedOption5) + "&6th=" + encodeURIComponent(selectedOption6) + "&7th=" + encodeURIComponent(selectedOption7) + "&8th=" + encodeURIComponent(selectedOption8) + "&9th=" + encodeURIComponent(selectedOption9) + "&10th=" + encodeURIComponent(selectedOption10);
        section3.style.display="none";
        section4.style.display="block";
        var u = "www.yoururl.com";
        var input = document.getElementById("1nameInput").value;
        var inputt = document.getElementById("copytxt");
        var inputname = "&name=";
      
        var  share = "&share=share";
        var text = u + url1 + share + inputname + input;
        inputt.value = text; 
        var $whatsApp = $('.whatsapp a');
       decorateWhatsAppLink(text, input);

 

    function decorateWhatsAppLink(text, input) { 
   
  // Getting user input 
  var message = "text"; 

  // Opening URL 
  var url = 'whatsapp://send?text=';
 
 //define the message text
 var textttt = 'dare take this Challenge Now ';
 
  
 //encode the text
 

 //find the link 

 var $whatsApp = $('.whatsapp a');

 //set the href attribute on the link
 $whatsApp.attr('href', url + input + textttt + text);
 
  
}
```

url come from text variable

please tell me how to do

Answer (score 0):

use encodeURIComponent on the whole URI not only the parameter values
so that `&` gets encoded as well ...

```
foo = "www.yoururl.com?1st=1&2nd=2&3rd=2&4th=1&5th=2&6th=2&7th=2&8th=2&9th=2&10th=2&share=share&name=s"

foo_final = encodeURIComponent(foo);
```